# How to list third party libraries in netbeans platform

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

Good morning dear all,
I developping a java application with Netbeans platform which is suppose to have hsqldb as embedded database. In order to use hsqldb.jar as package and database, I load it as a wrapped library. So, in the project, the library is store in {nbm_module_name}\release\modules\ext and in the distribution file, it is in {app_name}\modules\ext.

What I want is a correct way to access this jar in runtime and use it as database.

In simple java application (without netbeans platform), the code below work find. But I cannot use it for netbeans platform because wrapped libraries are not include in the standard java.class.path.
I try to use the library as a resource but it does not work and I don't like this approach as I'm suppose to load the same jar twice (as resources and as library).
Thank you very much for your help.

```
String[] strs = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(";");
    String dbUrl = "";
    for(String str : strs){
        if(str.contains("hsql"))
           dbUrl = str;
    }

      Connection connection = null;
      ResultSet resultset = null;
      Statement statement = null;

      Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:"+dbUrl, "sa", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Good,
the solution is the following. All external jar are locatated in the directory "ext" of "module" folder. And what I'm looking for is the jar "hsqldb.jar" which has "hsqldb" as unique name.

```
File file = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate("modules/ext", "hsqldb", false);
```

String dbUrl = file.getAbsolutePath()+"/hsqldb.jar";